# Number of connections do not seem to increase on increasing hibernate.c3p0.max_size

Tags: java, hibernate, connection-pooling, c3p0

My hibernate c3p0 config look like this.

```
hibernate.c3p0.min_size: 2
hibernate.c3p0.max_size: 50
hibernate.c3p0.timeout: 120
```

I run concurrent requests by wrk as:

```
wrk -t28 -c100  -d300s  http://app-host:8081/healthcheck
```

Note that this healthcheck api does a DB query  "select sleep(2)". To test the number of connections from app to db, I am doing netstat on db machine as,

```
sudo netstat -ntp | grep 3306 | grep app-host | wc
```

I get 58 connections which is somewhat close to c3p0 config,

```
hibernate.c3p0.max_size:50
```

But on increasing the same config to

```
hibernate.c3p0.max_size:100
```

I still get 58 connections in netstat. What am I missing ?

Edit(more info):
max_connections: 5000 on db.

Comment: Could you share more details on what is "wrk" and the "healthcheck api"? Are they in-house tools?

Comment: wrk is an HTTP benchmarking tool https://github.com/wg/wrk
& /healthcheck is just another HTTP api, which here does a "select sleep(2)" DB query.

Comment: I am not sure why the connections are going above 50 when the max_size is set to 50. Are you sure that the the config is being read by the application? Try setting the config such that the application errors out like changing the username.

Comment: Are you the only user connected to that db? is that app the only one using that db? You send 100 requests, 50 are handled, 50 wait *indefinitely* in a queue to get a connection until they get a connection or fail with timeout. Check [checkoutTimeout in the docs](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/).